# Check for TListItem duplicate before adding to Tlistview

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, tlistview

I have a list of `records` that I want to summarise into a `TListView`

The structure of the record is as follows

```
MyRecord = record
   SourceTable: string;
   SourceField: string;
   TargetTable: string;
   TargetField: string;
end;
```

In the record there may be multiple instances of SourceTable / TargetTable, with single instances of Source/Target Field

I would like to create a `TListView` in vsReport style that summarises each SourceTable\TargetTable pair.

Ideally I would like to do the following:

```
procedure SetTables;
var
   mp: MyPointer;
   LI: TListItem;
begin
   LI := LI.Create(nil);
   LI.Caption := ap^.SourceTable;
   LI.SubItems.Add(ap^.TargetTable);
   LI.Checked := not ap^.Updated;
   if lvMigration.Items.IndexOf(LI) = -1 then
       lvMigration.Items.AddItem(LI);
end;
```

i.e. Create a standalone TListItem, check that it doesn't already exist, then add it to my TListView.  However it breaks at the assignment of the `LI.Caption` - essentially there is nothing to assign to.  I suspect at least part of the problem is the `(nil)`

The normal creation of a TListItem would be to use `LI := lvMigration.Items.Add;` but this doesn't help my use case.  I can't seem to find any documentation where the above is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
LI := LI.Create(nil);
```

You meant to write

```
LI := TListItem.Create(nil);
```

This is the oldest Delphi mistake in the books and I'm sure you've made it before (we all have), and I'm sure you recognise it when you see it.

The rest of your code will not work though. You cannot do anything with a `TListItem` instance without supplying an `Owner`. For example, look at the implementation of `TListItem.SetCaption`:

```
procedure TListItem.SetCaption(const Value: string);
begin
  if Value <> Caption then
  begin
    FCaption := Value;
    if not Owner.Owner.OwnerData then
    .... 
  end;
end;
```

With your code, `Owner` is `nil` and so this code will just lead to an access violation. In fact you should not be instantiating `TListItem` ever. That's done by the container classes.

Even if without that issue, though, you would find that `IndexOf` does not do what you want. You want it to perform a search on the *value* of the item. But it performs a search on the *reference*.

What you will need to do is iterate through each item in the list and check its Caption and sub-items (or whatever identifies the item) against the prospective new value.

If you felt in the mood for a more drastic change, one that would make life easier in the long run, and improve performance if the list gets large, then switching to using the list view in virtual mode would help. You'd maintain a list of your items in a `TList<TMyItem>` or similar. And then you'd populate on demand. If you did that, then it would be much easier to detect duplicates since you'd be working with a plain container rather than a GUI control. Fundamentally you are making life hard for yourself by using a GUI control as a container class.

Comment: Oops.  In fact with the edit that you've pointed out it breaks at the `LI.Caption` and doesn't reach the `IndexOf` portion, so I hadn't managed to test that myself.  Will edit the question.

Comment: It doesn't matter. You don't need to edit the question. Please don't do that. Your entire approach cannot work. You'll need to do it the way I describe in my final paragraph.

Comment: Fair enough on the roll back.  And fair enough that the approach won't work, but you don't answer the core question - which is why does setting the value of `LI.Caption` fail (in spite of the typo in the question)?

Comment: @DanKelly I did not realise that was your core question. I'll extend the answer. Give me a minute.

Comment: That's pretty much what I thought (and tried to hint at). I'd hoped from the implementation of `TLisView.Items.AddItem` that there was a way to create a "virtual" TListItem but I suspect that this is only useful for moving TListItems from one TListView to another.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you sort your main list of records into a second list that has the duplicates filtered out, and then use the second list to populate the ListView. I would also suggest using the ListView in virtual mode (set its OwnerData property to true and then use its OnData... events). That will drastically improve the performance of your ListView, and you can then access/manipulate your records in memory and not be slowed down by the UI.